# How do I add vectors of different lengths?

Tags: r

I am trying to add two vectors.

- a is 41, 5
- b is 28, 5, 3, 1

I tried just simply doing this

```
c <- a + b
```

The answer came out as `69, 10, 44, 6`. I am guessing it reused a?

I want c to be `69, 10, 3, 1` after adding a and b together.

I have no experience with R at all so please keep the solution simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: here some suggestions to increase the probability of having a higher number of responses: Add a tag (in your case it seems the programming language is R). Try to format properly the question you have, for example, take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Try to provide a concrete example so people can copy and paste directly to the R console and to reproduce the problem you have. Here you can find some guidelines: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility could be:

```
c(a, rep(0, length(b) - length(a))) + b

[1] 69 10  3  1
```

Answer (score 3):

It is due to recycling.  We can prevent it by keeping the lengths same, but adding 0's

```
a1 <- `length<-`(a, length(b))
replace(a1, is.na(a1), 0) + b
#[1] 69 10  3  1
```

---

Or if there are multiple vectors, place it in a `list`, set the length programmatically and use `rowSums` which also have the `na.rm` parameter

```
lst1 <- list(a, b)
rowSums(sapply(lst1, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst1))), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 69 10  3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add two vectors of different sizes, R recycles the one of shorter length. See: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Recycling-rules. One solution is to pad out the shorter one with zeros as in tmfmnk's answer.